# In Java how can I play an ogg file provided by an https web service such as cerevoice?

Tags: java, web, service, ogg

I am trying to program a classroom assistant (I work as a teacher) using Java who will give spoken instructions to students/ask them questions etc. I have managed to connect successfully to the cerevoice cloud to create an ogg file 
e.g. "https://cerevoice.s3.amazonaws.com/Heather220501c8c2e94d4650f64f7d951bf76b08b0eb.ogg"
however when I try to play this ogg file from java I get an error that it could not be found or that it is an unsupported audio resource depending on the ogg player I use (i have tried EasyOGG and TinySound so far) - both the ogg players work successfully locally but I cannot get them to play a file directly from the website.
Examples how I have tried to reference it:

```
URL url = new URL("https://cerevoice.s3.amazonaws.com/Heather220501c8c2e94d4650f64f7d951bf76b08b0eb.ogg");
Music song = TinySound.loadMusic(url);
song.play(true);

OggClip ogg = new OggClip("https://cerevoice.s3.amazonaws.com/Heather220501c8c2e94d4650f64f7d951bf76b08b0eb.ogg");
ogg.loop();
```

Apologies for my ignorance I'd really appreciate any help anyone can give with playing this file! =)

Many thanks,

Darren

*Edited to show using a literal String value to help clarity*

Edit very ugly hack 1 solution: //opens a browser window plays file then closes window

```
String url = "https://cerevoice.s3.amazonaws.com/Heather220501c8c2e94d4650f64f7d951bf76b08b0eb.ogg"; //hard coded here for simplicity but URL dynamically retrieved from webservice
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));   
Thread.sleep(3000);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe");
```

Edit slightly less ugly hack 2 solution: 
//creation of a temporary file to allow playing from java without creating a browser window

```
  try{
  Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get("C:/cere/temp.ogg"));

  try (InputStream in = URI.create(url.value).toURL().openStream()) {
  Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C:/cere/temp.ogg"));
  }catch(IOException e)  {

  }
```

Comment: What happens? Does it throw any exception? Also, what is `url.value`? The `java.net.URL` class doesn't have any public field called `value`.

Comment: Edit your question to add code. Don't post it in comments, it is hard to read.

Comment: A really ugly hack I can use at the moment is just to open a browser window with the url put in but that's pretty horrific from a design point of view lol!
     java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(URLGOESHERE));

Comment: Other methods I've tried and failed with though are also just rubbish hacks really - org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile
throws a FileNotFoundException. and I get the same exception if I try to read in as an InputStream. Would love if a pro could help me access the file through an elegant solution! It seems crazy that web browsers can get to the file but not being able to from code. What do web browsers send that is enabling them to see the file that java can't do directly?

Comment: ugly hack now refined with a task kill to close the browser window it uses to play the file after - polishing the brown stuff comes to mind!

Comment: Have you had a look at this: http://www.jcraft.com/jorbis/tutorial/Tutorial.html